# How do you assign the type of an entire module to a destructured variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I am trying to add dependency injection to a CommonJS module, to make it easy to mock HTTP calls when testing.

Old code which works (Flow knows type of `http`):

```
const myModule = require('./my-module.js');
```

```
// my-module.js
const http = require('http');
module.exports = {
  doSomething: () => http.get(...);
};
```

New code, which doesn't work:

```
const myModule = require('./my-module.js')({http: require('http')});
```

```
// my-module.js
module.exports = ({ http }) => ({
  doSomething: () => http.get(...);
});
```

I get the error message “Missing type annotation for destructuring.” and I don't know what type annotation to use.

I have tried annotating the http property with various stuff and seeing what happens, but to no avail, e.g:

```
type ModuleOptions = $ReadOnly<{
  http: typeof require('http'),
}>;

module.exports = ({ http }: ModuleOptions) => ({
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was bound to happen. After spending several hours googling and trying things, within half an hour of posting on SO I'd figured it out:

```
import typeof HttpModule from 'http';
type ModuleOptions = $ReadOnly<{
  http: HttpModule
}>;

module.exports = ({ http }: ModuleOptions) => {
```